how to convert the compressed public key to the uncompressed one using ethers js sdk?
When create a wallet using the ethers library, only the compressed publick key(33bytes) is generated. how could i get the uncompressed public key(65 bytes)?

I'm guessing that by "compressed public key" you mean the address - which is 20 bytes (hex representation with 42 characters including the 0x prefix).
Address is the last 20 bytes of the keccak-256 hash of the public key. (source)
You can access all these items as properties of the Wallet type object in ethers.
Docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/wallet/
const {ethers} = require("ethers");

// 1. creates pseudo-random private key
// 2. derives public key from the private key
// 3. derives address from the public key
// 4. assigns all in the `Wallet` type object
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();

console.log(wallet.address);
console.log(wallet.publicKey);
console.log(wallet.privateKey);

